# Using Laravel Fluent is there a way to retrieve an updated or inserted row?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, fluent

For example I have the following query which updates a new row:

```
$query->where('email', '=', $user->email)->where('card_uid', '=', $k)
    ->update( array('email' => $user->email, 'card_uid' => $k, 'have_quantity' => ($card->have_quantity+$v)) );
```

I'd like to retrieve the updated (or inserted) row. I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
$row = $query->where('email', '=', $user->email)->where('card_uid', '=', $k)
    ->update( array('email' => $user->email, 'card_uid' => $k, 'have_quantity' => ($card->have_quantity+$v)) )
    ->get();
```

How can I retrieve the row I am updating or inserting easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the same query builder instance for the update first and then run the select query. (You can't do it the way you tried because `update()` returns the number of affected rows)

```
$query->where('email', '=', $user->email)->where('card_uid', '=', $k);
$query->update(array('email' => $user->email, 'card_uid' => $k, 'have_quantity' => ($card->have_quantity+$v)))
$row = $query->get();
```

Comment: By the way, why do you even need to retrieve the row after updating?

Comment: I don't have to but it's just how I'm confirming the database is up to date. I could update the client side without confirming the database but thought this would be cleaner and also easier to debug.

Comment: Hey, it's been awhile! :) I think I may have something to show you in about 2 months.

Comment: I see. I personally would rather just check that the return value of `update()` is greater than 0. Besides that, mostly when something fails with the update you will get an exception anyways...

Comment: Looking forward to that ;)